# Spinner com Itens customizado (imagem com fundo redondo e com cor)

Tags: android, spinners

Como faço um para um `Spinner` ser preenchido com itens, contendo uma imagem e o fundo redondo com uma cor?

Veja na imagem o que preciso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A tag [tag:android-studio] não é necessária.

Comment: De uma olhada [neste](http://www.edureka.co/blog/custom-spinner-in-android) tutorial

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407626/custom-layout-for-spinner-item Tenta usar adapter, como foi explicado no link acima. E ai vc utiliza um parâmetro pra indicar qual icone deve ser utilizado. É a forma que eu faria...